# Predict on new data with R random forest when there are missing data

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, predict

I want to predict on new data that contain NA rows.
I need to keep these rows to have the same number of rows in input data and prediction outputs.
How can I do this with a random forest model trained with R Caret ?
I tried different values for the argument na.action of predict function, for example :

```
predictions = predict(RF_model, newdata = newdata, type = "prob", na.action = "na.exclude")
```

With `na.exclude` and `na.omit` the rows are deleted. With `na.pass` I've got an error output "missing values".

EDIT : the model has already been trained, we are talking about predictions on completely new data, and some of them are not good. I know we can't predict on these bad data, but I need to keep a track of the rows.

Comment: This is common problem in data science. What you want to do is impute missing values, but there are multiple strategies to choose from. Which one is best in your case (or any case) is not on topic at Stack Overflow because it is not a programming question. However, if you have a specific imputation method that you are struggling to implement in R, that is on topic.

Comment: No, I don't want to impute missing values, I want to keep the lines with these missing values, so that the user knows the data are not good for prediction. So the question is : how to have NA in the prediction outputs. Here my inputs and my outputs have different number of rows and then I can't bind my dataframes to show the user the complete results. I thought using ```na.exclude``` would do the trick but this is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what you want. You want to take a trained model and make predictions on new data which may have missing values. Rather than impute the missing values, you want the predicted value to be `NA` for those rows with missing values.

Here is one way to do that. I can even maintain the original row order. The assumptions are that your new data is in a data.frame called `new_data` and your trained random forest model is called `my_forest`. Replace these with the names of your objects. I'm also assuming a regression model. If this is a classification problem, let me know and I can alter the code.

Here is a step-by-step method explaining what we are doing.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
new_data <- new_data %>% rowid_to_column() # add column with rownumber
new_data_na <- new_data %>%
  filter(!complete.cases(.))  # save those rows with NA in separate data.frame
new_data_complete <- new_data %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.))   # keep only those rows with no NA
new_data_complete$predicted <- predict(my_forest, newdata = new_data_complete) # make predictions
new_data_na$predicted <- NA_real # ensure that that NA is the same data type
new_data_predicted <- rbind(new_data_na, new_data_complete)  # bind rows
arrange(new_data_predicted, rowid) # return data to original order
```

Here is a mode code-efficient pipe method from using the tools of `dplyr`. Note how simple this looks. The `case_when` structure checks each row for NA values with `complete.cases(.)`. The `.` in the argument tells `complete.cases` to use all columns. If there are no `NA` values, `complete.cases(.)` returns `TRUE`, and the prediction runs on that row. Again, `newdata = .` is used to tell `predict()` to use all columns. If there is one or more `NA` values, `complete.cases(.)` will return `FALSE`. The second line of the `case_when` structure is a catchall for when the first line is not `TRUE`. If the first line is not `TRUE`, we want the predicted value to return `NA`. Note that this method does not involve taking the data apart, and so no effort needs to be made to put it back together.

```
library(dplyr)
new_data %>%
  mutate(predicted = case_when(complete.cases(.) ~ predict(my_forest, newdata = .),
                               TRUE ~ NA_real_)
```

Comment: Dear @Ben Norris, I tried to reproduce  your example but I get an error since NA_real object seems to be undefined and thus, doesn't exist. May I have forgotten something or is it necessary to fix something in the example's code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JLLavin - That's because I had a typo in my answer that went undetected for months. The correct way to specify a NA value that is a double type is `NA_real_`. Note the extra underscore at the end.

Comment: when I use predict as in your code (with my RandomForest model) predict(rfmodel, newdata = new_data_complete) I get the following error: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'rowId' not found May that be because "rowId" column was not among the variables/columns used to generate the model? Or does it have something to do with the code itself? Thanks in advance for your kind answer. PD. I'm going crazy trying to figure out a way to obtain the predictions/labels for each individual row of my input table using caret as R package for Machine Learning.